# Is there a good quality pocket camera with wide aperture?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, point-and-shoot, low-light

I'm looking for a pocket camera which performs well in low light conditions. I need a wide aperture such as f/2.4 or wider and I don't need to have zoom.

What would you recommend?

Comment: As I'm sure you know since you've got over a thousand reputation and have been around the site for several years, this kind of bare shopping recommendation is not a good fit for the site. See [this blog post on the subject](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) if you haven't already.

Comment: You must also know, if you're following digital cameras at all, that there are now a large number of compact cameras on the market which may fit your needs, depending on your individual definition of "pocket" and "performs good". Everything in DPReview's [Dec 2012 roundup of enthusiast compacts](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/2367736880/roundup-enthusiast-zoom-compact-cameras) will probably fit the bill. This year. But next year, the answers will change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify the price range, so [this](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/sony-cybershot-dsc-rx1) answers your question. The RX1 has a 35mm f2.0 prime lens with a full frame sensor. The only question is whether it's pocketable... I guess it depends on how deep your pockets are!

Answer (score 1):

You really want to check out the Sony RX-100. It is certainly pocketable and is f1.8 at its widest zoom level, which isn't half bad. The sensor is pretty large also, a bit smaller than the Micro 4/3rds cameras, but the results are pretty impressive from it. I love mine!

Answer (score 1):

Just get an iPhone 5, f2.4 baby

Comment: True, that does fit the stated conditions, and for a phone camera, it's not terrible in low light.

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone 5 is actually not as terrible as it might sound. Some great photos have been taken using just iPhones, and additionally, it can do reasonable quality 1080p Video as well.

If you prefer android, there's also the Nexus 4 route which has almost identical specs. Personally, I've used 3rd party applications to augment both devices and improve their low-light capabilities as well as allowing for long-exposures etc.

Worth considering if you don't have one already.